# How to put the taken photos in RecyclerView in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

My application uses the camera to take pictures and then saves them in the MediaStore. I would like to put these pictures in my RecyclerView using Glide but I don't know how to do it.

A function that saves the image:

```
private fun imageCapture() {

        // Set desired name and type of captured image
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, "${what_is_that_insect_tv.text}")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED.format("MM/dd/yyyy"), (Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis / 1000L))
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg")
        }

        // Create the output file option to store the captured image in MediaStore
        val outputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions
            .Builder(resolver, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)
            .build()

        // Initiate image capture
        imageCapture?.takePicture(
            outputFileOptions,
            cameraExecutor,
            object : ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback {
                override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                    // Image was successfully saved to `outputFileResults.savedUri`
                }

                override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                    val errorType = exception.imageCaptureError
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "$errorType", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })
    }
```

Function in Adapter

```
fun bind(insect: Insect){
           with(itemView){
               name_insect_item.text = insect.name
               Glide.with(this)
                   .load()
                   .into(this.image_insect_item)
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Glide you must obtain the URI of the saved image, in the onImageSaved I believe you can call .getSavedUri() like so :

```
override fun onImageSaved(outputFileResults: ImageCapture.OutputFileResults) {
                val uri = ImageCapture.OutputFileResults.getSavedUri()
            }
```

You should then be able to use the Uri in an ArrayList you feed to the adaptor. Got it from here :

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture.OutputFileResults#getSavedUri()

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Would be much appreciated if you could mark the answer as correct please :)

Answer (score 0):

I do this in my code like this:

```
 Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext())
     .load(new File(hotel.imageId2))
     .into(holder.imageView)
```

also this might help:

[RecyclerView- Glide](https://bumptech.github.io/glide/int/recyclerview.html)

Comment: I don't know how to take the photo path. If I know it, I can handle Glide